# QODBC3 Unable to bind to variable

Tags: c++, sql-server, database, t-sql, qt

I am attempting to add a new record to a table similar to the example listed below. When I run the query I get the following error: QODBC3: Unable to bind variable. What do I need to do to correct the error?

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO Table (id, val, time) VALUES (:id, :val, :time)");
query.bindValue(":id", 1);
query.bindValue(":val", "23");
query.bindValue(":time", QTime(8, 0));
query.exec();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess it doesn't know how to bind the QTime object.  Should you be using the toString method?

Comment: It was the attempt to bind it as a QTime object. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. turned on ODBC tracing
2. Double check your parameters!